# UITableView cells not populating with CloudKit data

Tags: ios, uitableview, cloudkit

I have an app that saves an array of 5 randomly generated colors via CloudKit. They are saved under Field Type of String (list). I'm able to save and retrieve the colors successfully.

In my app, I want to display each record with the array of colors on a different row. Currently, the correct number of rows show when data is retrieved, but only the first row has the array of colors (screenshots below). When I pull down on the table, it refreshes the rows and will show a different color array that was saved.

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class FavoritesController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

let paletteController = PaletteController()
    let favoritesTableView = UITableView()
    let reuseIdentifier = "favoritesCell"

    let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
    var retrieveFavoritePalette: [CKRecord] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTableView()
        queryDatabase()
    }

    func setupTableView() {
        favoritesTableView.dataSource = self
        favoritesTableView.delegate = self
        favoritesTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let heightOfCells: CGFloat = 100
        favoritesTableView.rowHeight = heightOfCells


        view.addSubview(favoritesTableView)
        favoritesTableView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)
    }

    func queryDatabase() {
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Favorite", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("Record retrieved")

                for record in records! {
                    self.retrieveFavoritePalette.append(record)
                }
            } else {
                print("Record not retrieved: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
            let sortedRecords = records?.sorted(by: { $0.creationDate! > $1.creationDate! })
            self.retrieveFavoritePalette = sortedRecords ?? []
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.favoritesTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return retrieveFavoritePalette.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        let paletteRecord: CKRecord = retrieveFavoritePalette[indexPath.row]
        var individualColorView: [UIView] = []
//        print(paletteRecord.value(forKey: "FavoritePalette"))

        let line = paletteRecord.value(forKey: "FavoritePalette") as? [String] ?? []

     //Creates the individual boxes where the color goes
        for i in 0..<5 {
            let xAxis = i * 20
            let individualView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xAxis, y: 0, width: 20, height: 80))
            individualColorView.append(individualView)
        }

        for j in 0..<line.count {
            let allColorsView = individualColorView[j]

            print(individualColorView[j])
            allColorsView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: line[j])

            tableView.addSubview(allColorsView)
        }

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
}
```

I tried putting `let paletteRecord...` to `tableView.addSubview(allColorsView)` into a TableViewCell class, but I got stuck when I couldn't figure out how to have the code compile without `indexPath.row` in `let paletteRecord: CKRecord = retrieveFavoritePalette[indexPath.row]`.

Output of `print(paletteRecord.value(forKey: "FavoritePalette"))` is `Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x6000039f98f0>( BBBB88, CCC68D, EEDD99, EEC290, EEAA88 ))`

This is what it currently looks like. I need each row to display the string array that was saved to CloudKit.
[image]

Data that's saved to CloudKit
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is on this line:

```
tableView.addSubview(allColorsView)
```

You are adding your color boxes to the `tableView`, but you probably meant to add them to the cell itself like this:

```
cell.addSubview(allColorsView)
```